# Why are code samples sometimes shown unformatted?

Tags: support, code-formatting, code

Sometime, I post questions (or answers for that matter), where code appears **unformatted** (without reserved words color, etc.), like the image below.
Why is that happening?

Here's an example to unformatted code:

[image]

On the other hand, this looks fine:

[image]